# Creating new dataframe based on maximum element

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes-

```
cols = ['A','B']
data = [[-1,2],[0,2],[5,1]]
data = np.asarray(data)
indices = np.arange(0,len(data))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=indices, columns=cols)

cols = ['A','B']
data2 = [[-13,2],[-1,2],[0,4],[2,1],[5,0]]
data2 = np.asarray(data2)
indices = np.arange(0,len(data2))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=indices, columns=cols)
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe which has for the same `A` the maximum of `B` from either dataframe.

Therefore, the output would be-

```
    A   B
0  -13  2
1  -1   2
2   0   4
3   2   1
4   5   1
```

Comment: Have you run into issues? What have you tried so far?

Comment: df1 has 3 rows, df2 has 5. When you say *"for the same A the maximum of B from either dataframe"* you mean "maximum of B for that specific row in either df".

Comment: Btw, you can just instantiate each dataframe in one line: `df = pd.DataFrame([[-1,2],[0,2],[5,1]], columns=['A','B'])`. You don't need to cast `data = np.asarray(data)`, and you don't need to generate and pass in the indices, it defaults to range-indices like you want. Makes your example much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align indices, concatenate and then take the maximum:

```
res = pd.concat([df.set_index('A'), df2.set_index('A')], axis=1)\
        .max(1).astype(int).rename('B').reset_index()

print(res)

    A  B
0 -13  2
1  -1  2
2   0  4
3   2  1
4   5  1
```

Comment: Could you explain the part after concat?

Comment: Sure, `max(1)` takes row-wise maximums, `astype(int)` converts to integers (otherwise you get `float` output). Since the resultant series has name `0` we need to rename as `'B'`. Finally, to elevate index to column we use `reset_index`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df2,df]).sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A',keep='last')
Out[80]: 
    A  B
3   2  1
2   5  1
0 -13  2
0  -1  2
2   0  4
```

Comment: For completeness / efficiency, we probably need `reset_index` to get rid of the duplicate indices.